# Test Cube/Test Rail - Test case Management Software

Tags: discussion

Has anyone used the test case management software 'Test Cube' or 'TestRail', we are currently looking for a test case management tool that can manage our automation and manual testing. We have tried 'test link' and attempted to use 'Testopia' although the UI caused confusion with some users.

It would be to good hear the following

- Advantages
- Disadvantages
- Any issues?

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: So there's a couple things. 1) The 'meta' site is for questions about the main site. Questions about tools should be on the main site. 2) I would migrate this there, but I'm not sure it's fleshed out enough. I don't see a real question to answer here. It's just "We want to use this or that, what are we in for?" which isn't a really good question archetype to be in.